# oauth2.0 authentication with code grant flow in Azure

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I have the following requirement:
I have a powerbi report with a simple table. One of the columns in the table is image. The powerbi user should be able to click on the button in the image column and it should then display the image in a web browser (or any other location where they can see the image displayed. The user shouldn't be able to download the image.

The images are stored in ADLS and the filepaths to the images can be dynamically generated in pbi. The first option I have tried is adding SAS token to the URL to then retrieve the image. This option was working fine but the problem is that anyone who could get access to the SAS token will then have access to the complete ADLS which has been flagged as insecure.

The other option I have been exploring is to create a function app that will first ask the user to authenticate and once successful return the image. Does anyone know whether it is possible to get this done with a single http request to the function app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you configure RBAC on ADLS with blob reader for the group that is allowed to view the images ?

Comment: We have configured RBAC on storage account level not on container level..

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use client credential flow which I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

For OAuth2.0 authentication you need Client secret client id and tenant id through which you can acquire a token, Once the Token is acquired the Function can be accessed like below:-

To get below credentials, you need to create an app in app registrations:
[image]

**`__init__.py :`**

```
import os
import azure.functions as func
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

# Azure AD settings
tenantid2 = "72f988bf"
clientid2 = "74230c16"
clientsecret2 = "IGj8Q~Iff"
rithscope = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default" 

def get_token_rith():
    authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid2}"
    app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
        clientid2,
        authority=authority,
        client_credential=clientsecret2
    )
    token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[rithscope])
    return token_response['access_token']

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    access_token1 = get_token_rith()
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello Rithwik, Authentication Successfull: {access_token1}")
```

**`requirements.txt:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would I use this token to then extract the image from ADLS? Also this authentication will not authenticate on the user level correct? It won't check whether the person calling the function is part of an AD group? So how can I ensure secure image retrieval in that case?